# Table is resizing when after text wraps

Tags: html, css

1. Open [pen](https://codepen.io/engineering-this/pen/BYyQeZ)
2. Focus last cell and write some text.

Table is resizing even if all text wraps into new lines. I want to keep `max-width` in percentage units, and `table-layout: auto`.

Any idea how css prevent that odd behaviour with css? As long as text is wrapping to new line it shouldn't extend table cell.

#### This occurs at least in chrome and safari.

Comment: The cell width is used as the basis for calculating the `div` width according to its `max-width` percentage. Give the `div` a `background-color` to see what's going on.

Comment: Unless you give your cells a width, they will always resize to what is in the cells.  Or you can add `table-layout:fixed;` to your table css - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQEOZp

Comment: This might give you some insights: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyBrRd

Answer (score 0):

add 100% width to your div, that is 100% width of table cell within.